# Strip Right channel in GarageBand

Tags: stereo

I have recorded some tracks in GarageBand using a stereo setting, but only actually recorded onto the left channel. The right channel, due to some normalisation I did, is full of white noise.

I currently have these tracks panned hard left. However, this means the whole output from the program is left channel only.

Is there a way to either:

1. Strip the right channel from the tracks, making them mono
2. Duplicate the left channel into the right

   or
3. Pan the 'hard left' output from all the tracks to the centre, using the overall GB controls? (All the tracks are recorded like this).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would move the tracks to something like Audacity and do the L/R channel editing there. Audacity lets you split a stereo track and make a copy of L to R and so on..

Ofcourse if you want to stick to Garageband, there is a long winded way.

Pan it hard left.
Export as mono. 
Re-import as mono..

I can't think of any quick and easy method.

Comment: I agree with this. You'll get better results with a waveform editor than in Garageband.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the only way to do it is through the hard way as above or use an external editor. Sadly Garageband is geared mostly towards music and less and less for audio editors and podcasters. Logic and SoundTrack Pro by Apple do this as well as Adobe Audition.

Sadly Audacity is terrible for this, since it won't let you manipulate audio files without creating projects. This ends up eating up a lot of disk space for what is essentially a temporary task. Smaller tools like MacSome (free) http://www.macsome.com/audio-editor-mac/index.html and Sound Studio http://felttip.com/ss/.